# IOS/Android app uploading videos to YouTube?

Tags: android, ios, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am developing an IOS/Andriod app where I want my users to be able to upload videos - these videos will later be used by the app. Since I don't want to spend a lot of money on data storage I was thinking of using YouTube as the placeholder of the videos.

- Is is scenario supported by YouTube?
- Are there any limitations for me to consider regarding this scenario?
- Is it OK if my app uses only one YouTube account - which my app users share and use when they upload a video? Or do my app users I have to use a personal YouTube account to upload the videos?
- Anything else I should think of which I might be missing here?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer you about android because I know about how you can achieve this in Android apps.
[Here's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) a simple step by step to learn how you can integrate Youtube in your android application. for doing this You will need to download the client libraries written in java. Download the library [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/api-client/google-api-client-assembly/1.18.0-rc/google-api-client-assembly-1.18.0-rc-1.18.0-rc.zip)

- This scenario is supported by Youtube
- It will be OK to use only 1 youtube account to upload videos to Youtube. but all users have to share that account
- One thing you can consider to make sure not to upload very large files (more than 100MB). although it will upload but it can take much time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to upload capture/gallery videos on your own channels, not possible to use like all users data storage.

Comment: What do you mean by "not possible to use like all users data storage"?